# How to cover at least 1 octave with voice?

Tags: voice

When I sing, I try to vocalize, but I don't succeed in singing one octave without forcing my chest voice. Is this normal?

I do about from Fa#2 to Fa3, and I force with Fa3. Is this normal or how do I correct it?

Comment: Hi! Are you talking about when you sing intervals, moving from one note, up directly one octave to another?

Answer (score 1):

Without wanting to sound glib, firstly, find a teacher, who should have enough experience and expertise to listen constructively and offer solutions to what appears to be a very restricted vocal range.

There are lots of exercises you should be doing, a lot of the time - in the shower, while driving ( or just in the car), etc., some will pop up to the right of your screen, as answers to other similar questions.

You may find, sadly, that you are part of a small minority of humans that were just not wired to be singers, but time will tell. Your age (unknown) will have a bearing on that.